# Is there any way to start mongo-connector in linux as a background process?

Tags: linux, redhat, python, fork

I am using **mongo-connector** to synchronize data between MongoDB and SOLR. I am working in **RedHat 7 OS Server**, I wanted to run the mongo-connector command as **fork** process in Server OS, since i need a realtime synchronization without any interruption.

I am issuing the command

```
sudo mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/Search --auto-commit-interval=0 -d solr_doc_manager
```

this will continue the mongo-connector service until i exit the command interface to the Server. How can i resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nohup or disown are the two tools I've used to do this in the past, not sure what mongo-connector & solr expect for their environment but try the following:

```
sudo nohup mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/Search --auto-commit-interval=0 -d solr_doc_manager&
```

Comment: I was failed to make linux service for mongo-connector. but Nohup works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or, have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Installation) (Installing as a Linux Service).

Comment: accidently missed this information from  wiki . Thank you :)